# Data Fetch Failure from Django REST API using useFetch in Nuxt.js: Different Behaviors on Reload and Code Editing

Tags: django, nuxt.js

I'm developing with Nuxt.js and attempting to fetch data from a Django REST API. I'm encountering several issues with the following code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ posts }}
    </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
const { data: posts, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch('https://localhost:8000/api/posts/')
console.log(posts, error)
</script>
```

Here are the problems I'm facing:

1. When using `useFetch` to retrieve data from the Django REST API, an error occurs. Specifically, the following log is output: `Proxy(Object) {mountains: Error: [GET] "https://localhost:8000/api/posts/": <no response> fetch failed at createError (…}`
2. If I edit and save the Vue code while the page is displayed, the data loads correctly, and I can see the requests in the server logs.
3. However, when I reload the page, the data does not load. There is no record of the request in the server logs.
4. If I change the URL to `https://fakestoreapi.com/products`, the data is fetched correctly even on page reload.

Could you advise on why the data doesn't load upon page reload and how I might resolve this? Also, if you have any insights into why the problem doesn't occur with a different URL, that would be very helpful.

### Add

I found the error returns status code 500. However Django server doesn't have any request log. How can I investigate more?

```
    yTUHiJnnBc: FetchError: [GET] "https://localhost:8000/api/posts/": <no response> fetch failed
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
        at async $fetchRaw2 (file:///Users/main/project/mynuxt/node_modules/ofetch/dist/shared/ofetch.00501375.mjs:228:14)
        at async $fetch2 (file:///Users/main/project/mynuxt/node_modules/ofetch/dist/shared/ofetch.00501375.mjs:261:15)
        at async setup (/Users/main/project/mynuxt/pages/blog/index.vue:14:216) {
      cause: [TypeError],
      statusCode: 500,
      fatal: false,
      unhandled: false,
      statusMessage: undefined,
      data: undefined,
      __nuxt_error: true
    }
  },
  _key: 'yTUHiJnnBc',
  _defaultValue: undefined,
  __v_isRef: true
```

Django server log.

```
[24/Dec/2023 15:03:28] "GET /api/posts/ HTTP/1.1" 200 304
```

It's comes from edited code. No2

---

I used the following code to configure the backend and made a request. The result was the same as above, and no requests were sent to the server when reloading. The status code for the request on the front end was 500. Are there any compatibility issues between Nuxt and Django?

```
def test_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Hello, World!'})
```

---

I found that the issue was reproduced when making requests from the Nuxt backend to a self-signed https server.

server/api/posts.js

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const data = await $fetch('https://localhost:8000/api/posts/')
    return data
})
```

### Enviroment

- Node v20.10.0
- npm 10.2.3
- MacOS 13.6（22G120）
- Python 3.11.5
- Django==4.2
- django-sslserver==0.22
- djangorestframework==3.14.0

Comment: I was able to retrieve the data by starting Django with `http` instead of `https`. It appears that HTTPS self-signing is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

So since you are using localhost with SSL I am going to assume you are also using SSR so the reason it fails on refresh is because its running server side, and a hmr refresh would just run the client side thus it would work.  At least thats is what I just ran into.

Try adding this to your .env it is what worked for me.

NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0

Comment: thank you. I've confirmed that the backend request is the problem. However, in my case, `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` did not solve the problem.